# Ndef.get(tag) returns null - Mifare support in Android

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

**1.**  `ndef` object returned is always **null**.

```
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent: "+intent.getAction());       
    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.message_tag_detected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
    ndef.connect();
```

`Tag` object return is

```
TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable]
```

**2.** I have one UAE resident identity card which has embedded NFC, Can this code be used to scan it? Is it Mifare?

**3.** Using NFC TagInfo app on playstore, scan result gives warning

> Mifare Classic is not supported on your device!

**4.** Does android have full support for Mifare? I couldn't find the source code online.

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: No update yet...

Comment: able to read any data from Emirates ID using NFC?

Answer (score 2):

1. Ndef object is made from the tag techlist that contains `android.nfc.tech.Ndef`
   as the card that you used didn't have this, hence, the object is always null.
   Try with a card that has `android.nfc.tech.Ndef` in its techlist and you'll get the object.
2. You can check if the device is mifare by the techlist in tag. look for `android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic` , the cards with this tech in it list are Mifareclassic cards.
3. To read and write Mifare classic cards your device must have nxp ic (NFC is primarily needed for all RFID chips but you need nxp for mifare specially).
   You can check if the device has nxp ic from the below code:

   ```
   getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("com.nxp.mifare");
   ```
4. Yes, Andriod provide full support to Mifare classic cards. I know there is no straightforward code for this as I have been in the situation a time ago.
   But the code is available, you can check the google code for all the NFC cards and extract the one you need for your card type here:
   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.java

or visit my repository for exact working code to scan Mifare Classic cards  here:
https://github.com/codes29/RFIDReader/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/codes29/rfidreader/MainActivity.java